# rails 3 - SQL pass variable to "order"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3

Im trying to pass variable to the order...

```
[code].order(['SUM((prices.price * ?) + profiles.shippingCost)', params[:prod_id]]).all
```

But it doesn't convert the variable to sql instead it gives me.(the variable in this case was "1").

```
GROUP BY price ORDER BY SUM((prices.price * ?) + profiles.shippingCost), 1):
```

Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
[code].order("SUM((prices.price * #{params[:prod_id].to_i}) + profiles.shippingCost)").all
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly, spent a couple of hours looking for a solution. Have a nice sunday :)